# Harmonic real function, $\triangle f =0$, but not in origin?

Tags: partial-differential-equations

**Problem in English** (original problem 7 on page 813 [here](https://noppa.aalto.fi/noppa/kurssi/mat-1.1020/materiaali/Mat-1_1020_juhani_pitkaranta__tkk_n_laaja_matematiikka_ii__2007_.pdf?state:CourseAdditionalMaterial=BrO0ABXcgAAAAAgAAGWVkaXRVc2VyV2FudHNUb0NoYW5nZUZpbGVzcgARamF2YS5sYW5nLkJvb2xlYW7NIHKA1Zz67gIAAVoABXZhbHVleHAAdxMAABBlZGl0RGlhbG9nSGlkZGVuc3EAfgAAAQ==))

> Suppose $f(|\bar{x}|)=\sqrt{x_{1}^2+...+x_{n}^{2}}$. For what kind of
>   real $f$ it holds that $f$ is harmonic everywhere but not in origin? If $f$ is harmonic, then $\triangle f=0$.

**Definitions**

> The *"real function"* apparently here means some $g$ such that $g: \mathbb R^{n}\to\mathbb R$, not
>   vector in the co-domain but scalar (can be realized by looking at the norm) but $\bar{x}\in\mathbb R^n$ (please verify).

*I am not sure whether this problem is just a brute-force calculation -practise or some clever trick, below some of my calculations for one term, not summing it up because it is a messy.*

[image]

Comment: Work out what it means for $\Delta f=0$. In other words, you are summing $\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x_i^2}$ which you can use the chain rule on to get in terms of $f''(|x|)$ and everything else that is in your above expression. When you sum that's when you will get 0. Do not expect that each individual term gives you 0.

Comment: I can't read the PDF because it is not in English. Could you please post the full question? Are you looking for all harmonic functions on the punctured plane $\mathbb{R}^2-\{0\}$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, if $f(r)$ is a scalar function and $g: \mathbb{R}^n\to \mathbb{R}$, we have
$$\Delta f(g) = \nabla \cdot \nabla f(g) = \nabla \cdot (f'(g) \nabla g) = f''(g)\nabla g\cdot\nabla g + f'(g)\Delta g.$$
When $g(\mathbf{x}) = \|\mathbf{x}\|$, we have, by direct computation, $\nabla g = \hat{\mathbf{x}}$ and $\Delta g = (n-1)/\|\mathbf{x}\|$. Therefore
$$\Delta f(g) = f''(g) + f'(g)(n-1)/g,$$
which vanishes whenever $f$ satisfies the ordinary differential equation
$$rf''+(n-1)f'=0.$$
My ODE chops are not up to finding a general solution (I'm sure someone will post an answer completing this step), but as a sanity check note that the expected $f(r) = \log r$ does work when $n=2$.

Comment: ...yes this is the way to do it, then the last part of this problem is to solve the second-degree differential-eq where $f=f(r)$ (so cannot use the Euler here but $g(r)=y'(r)$ and that way to solve it as a first degree). One can show that the above holds by writing things such as $\triangledown=\bar{i} \partial_x+\bar{j} \partial_y+\bar{k} \partial_z$ open. Also, notice that the $r$ is the distance from origin.Thanks, I think I am now on the right track about this problem, +1.